# Cannot access Internet from Windows 8 on VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-8-preview

I recently installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview on Oracle VirtualBox on my Windows 7 laptop. All's well, but I am unable to access Internet from Windows 8. Any ideas?

Comment: I would add some screenshots late this evening.

Comment: Well, I went onto create screenshots... and lo it started working. :) The internet connection is on now. Don't know what the issue was.. .weird...